# Where are the variables stored for mate-calc?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, mate-desktop, calculator

I know that there's no way to delete them by default in the application, but they have to be stored somewhere?  I'm pretty handy with the command line, so I can do some such there.

I believe that mate-calc is based on gcalctool, so perhaps the solution to one is the same as the other?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I suppose I should have looked around a bit more thoroughly before I popped in and asked here.

Solution from [here](http://bobthegnome.blogspot.com/2010/03/gcalctool-530.html):

> Variables can't be removed (the workaround is to edit
>   ~/.local/share/gcalctool/registers)

Obviously for mate-calc the part that says gcalctool becomes mate-calc.

Hope that helps someone else!